# Ping, nslookup and tracert works, but I can't access server via browser - any ideas?

Tags: networking, router, browser, dns, ping

My office has a SBS 2011 running remote.domain.com/owa as a webmail service. I suddenly can't access this site in my browser anymore. Strange thing is that I can ping the domain with no losses. I can tracert the domain and the route comes up nice. I can also nslookup the domain and I get all the correct information. But I can't access the OWA with my browser.
I have tried it with two different PC's, an iPad, a HTC One and an iPhone. None of them can access OWA with the browser.

My home router is a Cisco RV220W. Any idea on whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like exchange is down or at least the OWA website. Can you access your email otherwise? Check IIS Manager on that machine and verify that the OWA site is up. Have any other sites been created on that server recently? There could be a port conflict. Can you navigate to the root site at remote.domain.com?

Comment: I've just tried with my iPad and HTC One with WiFi disabled and on 3G and here i can connect without any problems. So the problem must be elsewhere than on the server. Root side of remote.domain.com is on a hosted server, and there isn't any problems with this site.

Comment: So maybe we need a better understanding of how this site is configured logically. If I'm assuming correctly, the remote.domain.com/owa URL is being forwarded to your SBS server for external requests. This sounds like a DNS issue. Externally this is handled by your router and seems to be forwarding to the correct IP and port since you are able to access via 3G, but internally the DNS server is not resolving that URL to the proper local IP.

Comment: So what you are saying is: from my router to work-server the DNS works but from my router to my devices, the DNS doesn't work? How do I solve this?

Comment: Any ideas on solving the problem?

Comment: A little bonus info: I can successgully connect to the server through VPN from my home WiFi, using remote.domain.com as connection...